# How to add fade out after few seconds in append content in javascript

Tags: javascript, append, jquery-animate, fadeout

first of all, I am not sure how to ask this properly. I hope you can understand based on the piece of code I provide below.

The code below basically appends every new content from bottom to top. I would like to make every new content to fade out after a few seconds. So that means, once every new content appear, it will fade out after few seconds.

```
function addContent(payload) {
    // Container
    let content = $('#paper');
    content.append("<div class='item'>" + payload + "</div></br>");

    // Scroll top bottom
    content.animate({ scrollTop: content.get(0).scrollHeight }, 333);
}
```

I found this code `.fadeIn('fast').delay(5000).fadeOut('fast')` somewhere on the internet but I don't know how to use it with the code I have up there.

Comment: The "code found somewhere on the internet" looks like jquery. You could just add a css class that has an animation making it vanish, then maybe remove it with js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
function addContent(payload) {
    // Container
    let content = $('#paper');
    $("<div class='item'>" + payload + "</div></br>").appendTo(content).fadeOut(500);
    // Scroll top bottom
    content.animate({ scrollTop: content.get(0).scrollHeight }, 333);
}
```

**Explanation:**

While using JQuery you need to first Select an element and than apply the respective function to it.

So first we select the element which is `$("<div class='item'>" + payload + "</div></br>")` and then append it into the appropriate place which will become
`$("<div class='item'>" + payload + "</div></br>").appendTo(content)`
[Creating New Elements](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

Then we will apply the fadeOut function to our New Element and the final result will be `$("<div class='item'>" + payload + "</div></br>").appendTo(content).fadeOut();`
More details about [fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

JQuery applies the method to what is Selected.